# How do I change the display type of a Bootstrap 3 modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

By default, bootstrap modals are set to `display: block;`. How can I change this to `display: flex;`? I would like to avoid adding JavaScript to fix this if possible.

This code makes it so the modal has `display:flex` but it is always visible. I am assuming this is because bootstrap by default makes this a `display:hidden`.

```css
#HelpModal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is my modal, `$RenderedAdminHelpModal` is not causing an issue here. I am using SilverStripe to render the content of this modal.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#HelpModal">Tutorial</button>
<div id="HelpModal" class="d-flex p-2 modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        $RenderedAdminHelpModal
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is, most likely, an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You probably think changing the modal's display to `flex` is solving a problem. What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: *"You **don't** change the display property of a Bootstrap 3 modal"*.

---

Looking at your code, I'm guessing the reason why you want to change its `display` property is because you want to vertically centre it.

Vertically centring a Bootstrap 3 modal is not as easy as it may seem, for at least two reasons:

First and foremost, Bootstrap changes its `display` property on the fly when showing/hiding it. I wouldn't recommend overriding that property.

Then you have a different, even more delicate problem. Vertically centring a tall child in a short parent, with `flex`, makes the top and bottom of the child go outside of the parent. And when the parent is the size of the viewport, you end up not being able to scroll to the start of the child.
In short, when the modal holds enough content to become taller than the viewport, you can no longer scroll to its top. And that's a huge accessibility problem.

A decent solution for Bootstrap 3 modals is to limit the height of the modal (making sure it is ***never*** taller than the viewport) and place a scrollbar, when needed, on the modal's body.

Here's how:

```css
@media (min-height: 270px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .modal-content {
    width: inherit;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .modal-footer,
  .modal-header {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
  .modal-body {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .modal-dialog {
      height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }
    .modal-content {
      max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }
  }
}
```

See it working:

```css
@media (min-height: 270px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .modal-content {
    width: inherit;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .modal-footer,
  .modal-header {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
  .modal-body {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .modal-dialog {
      height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }
    .modal-content {
      max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }
  }
}

.modal-title {
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.modal-header button.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.5rem;
  top: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Large modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large tall modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Large tall modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small tall modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Small tall modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-xs">Small short modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-xs" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myExtraSmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Small short modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why wrapped in a `min-height` media query? Because it doesn't render well on viewports with a height below `200px` (the `.modal-body` content becomes hard to access, because of the limited element height).
But we don't really want vertical centring on those screens, do we? The main concern there is accessibility. And Bootstrap 3 provides it out of the box, if we don't interfere.